# ADO.NET retrieve a user from the database with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have always used linq to get data from sql. It's fast and easy to use but I've heard it requires more resource from the server compared to normal queries.

So.. I'm trying to get better with queries now..

**What I want is to retrieve a user from the database, with a query.**

Is it possible to do something like this:

**User model:**

```
[Key]
public int UserId { get; set; }  

public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
public string Money { get; set; }
```

**Query:**

```
public User GetUser(string userName)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = @UserName";

    User user = null;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = userName;

            connection.Open();

            user = (User)cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    return user;
}
```

Or am i forced to use datareader and insert every cell into a new user model, and then return it?

//Newbie

**Update 1:**

How would i proceed if I want the result to be a genericcollection of user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SqlDataReader` is just a handle to the results, kind of like a cursor. You need to step through it and pick out the values, indexed by the result's column names. Try something like this:

```
public User GetUser(string userName)
{
  string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = @UserName";
  User user = null;
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
    try
      {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = userName;
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read()) {
          // Now you're pointed at the first result row
          user = new User {
            UserID = dr["UserID"],
            Name = dr["Name"],
            Whatever = dr["Whatever"]
          };
        }
      }
      catch
      {
      }
    }
  return user;
}
```

Also, ADO.NET now recommends using the `Parameters.AddWithValue` method. I find it a lot easier because you don't have to deal with types and lengths and so forth, and I've never had any problems with results. So, instead of this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = userName;
```

You can use this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
```

Comment: Thank you veeeeery much! This really cleared things up.

Comment: How normal is it for companies to actually use queries instead of linq? Is it really that big of a difference in terms of performance? Doesn't linq convert itself in some magical way to queries?

Comment: Linq definitely converts magically to queries. Straight queries rather than Linq are perfectly normal, and I think they're essential when complex queries are involved. For the straightforward stuff, such as the query in your question, Linq is probably a lot easier and I doubt you'd have any performance worries at the server - you may lose a few ticks in your code as .NET converted the Linq to a SQL query, but probably not enough to notice.

Answer (score 1):

No, unlike Linq and ORM layers, basic ADO doesn't map from database to entities. You must read each column value and assign to each property yourself.

However, you may want to try Dapper. It does support what you are trying to do while still retaining the low level syntax, speed and efficiency of SQL. It is implemented as extension methods for IDbConnection.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net